# NullpointerException while reading a json with null value for array

Tags: java, json, jackson

Is there a way to read this json without causing nullpointer exception through jackson.

```
{
    "years": [
        null
    ]
}
```

years is an array of String

Also is that a valid format of json when there are no years?

Comment: How are you reading it? Please include all the relevant code.

Comment: If you want to send an empty array for years, then send it as `{ "years" : [] }`

Answer (score 2):

If you look closely at the tutorials for Jackson, you will see that the JSON this library produces itself for empty arrays uses this notation: `{ "empty" : [ ]}`

Therefore you may try replacing any singular `null` value in an array with just an empty array before sending your JSON to Jackson, it should accept without throwing any exceptions.

Canonically, a ' null' member of an array is actually valid JSON syntax. See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON. Members of an array can be of any type, thus they can be:

- Strings
- Numbers
- Booleans
- Arrays
- Objects
- null

For your usage scenario however, I would recommend using the empty array instead, because it is simply far easier to program with. For example, consider a usage case where you call some function `f()` on each of your 'years' which wants an integer input. Code like 
    `foreach(x in array){f(x);}` will fail because you will call `f()` with a 'null' type instead of an integer, causing errors. If you instead used the empty array, the correct behaviour will happen without having to treat the case where there are no years diffrently by explicitly looking for the null. Just makes your life easier that way.